# Comma separated Multiple keyword search

Tags: python, sqlite, web.py

I am using Web.py and sqlite3.I have a library catalog stored in database with following schema

`booklog(id,book_name,author,genre,language)`

I want to search through the database through a single text field.for eg if I type XYZ Ishould get all the results where XYZ occurs whether as author/book name/genre.I am getting this result with simple query with OR.The issue I have right now is when I want to search for multiple keywords separated by comma through the same textfield.the result should be with rows having both keywords followed by single keyword match.

I am able to split the keywords in to  a list and search .but I am unable to sort the table with Descending no of matches ,also the collate nocase does not work in a list:

```
 inp=web.input()
 key=inp.search.split(',')
 myvar=dict(t=key)
 result=db.query("select * from booklog where book_name in $t collate nocase or author in $t collate nocase or genre in $t collate nocase ",myvar)
 return render.bookview(result)
```

Is there any other way to do this in web.py??I am relatively new to python/web.py/sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a full text search engine such as Solr. Engines such as that would automatically rank the results in the way you want them.

If you still want to do it with sqlite3 alone, have a look at its [Full Text Search Extension](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)

In particular, look for Phrase queries in [this section](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3). With the support for phrase queries, you don't need to even split your input string into lists.

Comment: yes I want to do with sqlite3.the FTS but does not mention about matching in list.anyway thank you so much for the fast reply. :)

Comment: You don't use a list with FTS. You directly search for your string. Setting up the FTS tables is what involves effort on your part.

Comment: @Rishin - See my updated answer and please read that section.

Comment: Thank you again :).but still how to covert a normal database to fts table.how to populate the fts table with my current values in the database.

Comment: You should first accept this answer. Then try to create and populate a FTS table and then open a new question with any errors you get. People on SO will respect you a lot if you show some effort. We'll gladly ignore anyone who'd want us to do their work :)

Comment: Oh!!I really didn't mean that.Anyway thank you so much.I will try to implement fts and will come back if I have some errors.:)

Comment: @Rishin - I am here for around another 8 hours. So, if you come back with problems, you'll get a prompt reply. If you show us some errors, others will also join in. Also, upvoting is not the same as accepting. You need to click on the checkmark next to the answer.